# Set Sitecore field sharing across all templates in a project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sitecore, sitecore6

I need to set the Shared property on a lot of template fields to false. Is there an easy way to do this in code without the field IDs changing? I have written the following code but it doesn't seem to update the property.

```
Sitecore.Data.Database masterDb = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");

using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
{
    try
    {
        var templates = TemplateManager.GetTemplates(masterDb);

        foreach (var template in templates.Values)
        {
            if (template.FullName.StartsWith("FolderName"))
            {
                foreach (var field in template.GetFields(false))
                {
                    TemplateManager.ChangeFieldSharing(field, TemplateFieldSharing.None, masterDb);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While the `TemplateManager.GetTemplates` call gets you a collection of `Template` objects what you need is the `TemplateItem` object in order to be able to edit it. You can use the ID to get that from your existing`Database` object.

You then need to iterate into each `TemplateSectionItem` of the template before you can get at the `TemplateFieldItem` where you can reach into the `InnerItem` property and make a change to the shared field. You also need to mark `BeginEdit()` and `EndEdit()` so that you can perform the change.

```
Sitecore.Data.Database masterDb = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");

using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
{
    try
    {                     
        var templates = TemplateManager.GetTemplates(masterDb);

        foreach (var template in templates.Values)
        {                         
            if (template.FullName.StartsWith("FolderName"))
            {                             
                var tmpl = masterDb.GetTemplate(template.ID);

                foreach (var section in tmpl.GetSections())
                {                                 
                    foreach (var templateFieldItem in section.GetFields())
                    {
                        templateFieldItem.BeginEdit();
                        templateFieldItem.InnerItem[TemplateFieldIDs.Shared] = "0";
                        templateFieldItem.EndEdit();   
                    }    
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Error" + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This looks like a solid solution. +1

Comment: Looks like... but does it raise FieldSharingChangedRemoteEvent? I'm not really sure.